# How can I add online song download for music player in android studio?

Tags: android, kotlin, download, audio-streaming

I am new dev for Android studio.I want a create music player.But,this music player online songs download then will play ve and read song from storage. I'm a little inexperienced at this. I don't know how to download songs from internet with code to my project. Which method, code, library or API should I use? I want to use kotlin language. Who can help me with this issue

Comment: You don't have to download the songs. Instead you can parse them by Uri.parse("your song link". Downloading doesn't make sense here

Comment: But when this happens, doesn't the app automatically download the song when starting?

Comment: No,  Uri parses the song link.  Note it doesn't download it.

Comment: Parsing is to read the value of one object to convert it to another type. For example you may have a string with a value of "10". Internally that string contains the Unicode characters '1' and '0' not the actual number 10.

Comment: So in your case,  Uri  converts your song link to a actual song that can be played using MediaPlayer.

Comment: And you are specifying that you have to store the song in storage. For that you can use File in Java.

Comment: You can convert your uri to file by ````new File(uri.getPath());````

Comment: Is there a sample source code?

Comment: Yes. I m posting answer so please check it.

Comment: @ElPrimo where is your answer?

Comment: Kindly check the answer. Actually i fell asleep while trying to write answer as it was night

Comment: You are very kind. Thank you.

Comment: String file = downloadFile("yourweb.com/music.mp3", files)   Will I write my own database in this section?

Comment: Can I write on any site like youtube

Comment: No. You will write your song link.

Comment: ````Can I write on any site like youtube```` I didn't understand. What are you trying to do on youtube

Comment: You can accept the answer if it helps you

Comment: Will I write my own database in this section?

Comment: No your song link

Comment: the link from where you are playing songg

Comment: You can accept the answer if it helps you

Comment: Have you tested the code? Does it works

Comment: I understand thank you.

Comment: No,i have not test.

Comment: So test it first

Comment: i will try your code

Comment: Is there an application code you would recommend to me on github

Comment: AT the moment, no

Comment: How can I bind this to a button?

Comment: search by opening the download menu and entering the song

Comment: TO bind this function into a button you have to write the second code in the button onclick listerner

Answer (score 1):

This code works:

```
private static void downloadFile(String url, File outputFile) {
  try {
      URL u = new URL(url);
      URLConnection conn = u.openConnection();
      int contentLength = conn.getContentLength();

      DataInputStream stream = new DataInputStream(u.openStream());

        byte[] buffer = new byte[contentLength];
        stream.readFully(buffer);
        stream.close();

        DataOutputStream fos = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outputFile));
        fos.write(buffer);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
  } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
      return; 
  } catch (IOException e) {
      return; 
  }
}
```

Make sure you have `Manifest.permissions.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` declared in your Manifest.

Then

```
File files = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString());
String file = downloadFile("yourweb.com/music.mp3", files);
String directory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/music.mp3";
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, directory);
try {
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

mediaPlayer.start();
```

Result is not guaranteed. You can try it